# Faster way of converting image hex dump to binary array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, image, hexdump, cfdata

I need to edit the pixels' raw binary values of an image. For this, I did this steps:

1. I obtained the CFData containing the hex dump of the image.
2. I converted the CFData obtained to an array of characters (using convertToArray function)
3. After that, I used convertToBinaryString function to obtain a string representing the base 2 value of the hex dump.

It does work and does the job for small files but when it comes to bigger ones it takes forever to finish. I failed in the struggle of finding a faster way. Could you help me?

Down here you can take a look of the functions I need to optimize:

```
func convertToArray(imageData : CFData) -> Array<Character>{
  let arrayData : Array<Character> = Array(String(NSData(data: imageData)).characters)
  print("Array : ")
  Swift.print(arrayData)
  return arrayData
}

func convertToBinaryString(array : Array<Character>) -> String{
    let numberOfChars = array.count
    var binaryString = convertHexToBinary(array[1])
    for character in 2...numberOfChars - 2{
        binaryString = binaryString + convertHexToBinary(array[character])
    }
    // print("BINARRY ARRAY : ")
    // print(binaryString)
    return binaryString

}
```

Comment: I'm curious, if you ultimately want a binary representation in `0`s and `1`s, why store that in a `String`?

Comment: `imageData` *is* the binary data. Then you create a string with the hex description of that data, and extract the bytes again ...

Comment: When you say you need to edit the raw binary values how exactly are you editing them? Do you need a certain range of values at a time?

Comment: @ColGraff For certain pixels, I want to change a value of 1 in the binary representation to 0. This is what I mean by editing them.

Comment: @MartinR , maybe I can not express my thoughts . Instead of " ffffffff ", I need " 11111111111111111111111111111111 " and for some of the pixels I want to change some values of 1 with values of 0. This is the 'binary data' I need for my images.

Comment: @AMomchilov I thought this would be an easy way of replacing some of the values in the binary pixel representation. If you could suggest me a better way, please feel free to help. :)

Comment: An array of Booleans seems more appropriate, IMO. Or an enumeration.

Comment: @AMomchilov Thank you! I was thinking about UnsafeMutablePointer to retain that information I need. I believe this would speed up the execution, but unfortunately I am not sure of how to implement a method using U.M.P. for both extraction and converting the infos.

Comment: @ch_studend Why would you use UnsafeMutablePointer?

Comment: @AMomchilov I was thinking to use it to enhance the rapidity of the execution.

Comment: @ch_studend And how do you suppose using UnsafeMutablePointer can achieve that?

Comment: @AMomchilov So far, I honestly have no clue of how to explain and neither of how to implement it in a decent way :)

Comment: @AMochilov  I managed to find a way to solve my problem using UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> . It does, indeed make the job a lot faster. :D

Answer (score 0):

I would try this extension to `NSData` that provides a [`CollectionType`](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_CollectionType_Protocol/index.html) interface. It seems like it would make it much easier for you to do your modifications without having to much around with `UnsafeMutablePointer`:

[Bytes collection for NSData](https://gist.github.com/rnapier/da148690af63c401097d)

Since `BytesView` and `MutableBytesView` are a `CollectionType` it gives you subscripting, indices, and more so you can iterate through your data and make the changes you want.

The article which is relevant to this question and introduces that linked code:

[NSData, My Old Friend](http://robnapier.net/nsdata)

Comment: Note that in Swift 3, most of this will be built-in. The new `Data` struct is a MutableCollection.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am going to lecture what you told me and try to implement a method using this information.

Comment: @RobNapier I can't wait for it, Swift 3 is going to shake things up and provide a lot of great changes. Oh and I hope you continue posting on your blog, I've learned quite a few useful tips from it. Thanks!